# Turn more than one light on or off in Javasript

Tags: javascript

I am programming a room, with different lightbulbs. The bulbs should be turned off or on individually. I should be possible to add an id on the change function. I have created the bulbs on the 'server' where I have access to the images and define the position.

All he different bulbs get their position in the new bulb, the Javascript should turn them on or off.

```
    private final Bulb[] bulbs = new Bulb[]{
            new Bulb(1, true, "white", "slaapkamer", 92, 31),
            new Bulb(2, false, "soft", "slaapkamer", 374, 31),
            new Bulb(3, true, "blue", "trap", 493, 325),
            new Bulb(4, false, "clear", "keuken", 832, 49),
            new Bulb(5, false, "soft white", "wc", 1109, 37),
            new Bulb(6, false, "normal", "douche", 1212, 251),
            new Bulb(7, true, "onmove", "outside", 606, -71),
    };


function change() {
    var image = document.getElementById('switch');
    var lightBulb = setBulbStatus(1, function(lightBulb) {

    document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};


        if (lightBulb.on) {
            image.src ='img/bulb-on.png';
        }
        else {
            image.src ='img/bulb-off.png';
            }

        });
}

function setBulbStatus(bulbId, okCode){
    let url = new URL("/setBulb", document.baseURI);
    url.searchParams.append("bulbId", bulbId);
    console.log("Before fetch")

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Before fetch")
            console.log(data)
            okCode(data);
        },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    console.log("After fetch")
}

function positionBulbs(){
    let floorPlan = $("#floorplanContainer")
    let lightbulbOff = "img/bulb-off.png";
    let lightbulbOn = "img/bulb-on.png";

    fetchBulbs(function(bulbs){
        bulbs.forEach(function(bulb){
            let lightBulbSrc = bulb.on ? lightbulbOn : lightbulbOff;
            let img = $("<img>");
            img.attr("id", bulb.id)
            img.attr("src", lightBulbSrc)
            img.css({top: bulb.yPosition, left: bulb.xPosition, position:'absolute', height: 65, width: 65});
            floorPlan.append(img);
        });
    });
}

function fetchBulbs(okCode){
    let url = new URL("/bulbs", document.baseURI);

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            okCode(data);
        },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    positionBulbs();
});

function fetchBulbs(okCode){
    let url = new URL("/bulbs", document.baseURI);

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            okCode(data);
        },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

Comment: Doing this manually is error-prone and time-consuming. You should consider using a data-binding framework like Knockout.js or even Vue.js. It makes your life so much easier.

Comment: What is your question? What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: I am creating a room with lightbulbs and I have written some code to turn the lightbulb on and off. 
It is working fine, the thing is I would like to use the same code for different bulbs, all my bulbs have an id, so how can I change the code so it will work for more than one bulb?

Comment: You haven't shown even a half of the code involved in this. We need to see much more code to say, how this would/wouldn't work with multiple bulbs ...

Comment: This is not clear. `change` is never called; `myFunction` is nowhere defined; `fetchBulbs` is defined twice; `setBulbStatus` is a function that always returns undefined, yet you assign it to the `lightBulp` variable, so you could never evaluate `lightBulp.on` successfully. I don't really see how you say this works for you. And what is the purpose of the `demo` click handler?? This question really needs some improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have to update the img attribute in the fetchbulbs. something like this:
$(selector).attr(attribute,function(index,currentvalue))

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to store the bulb's id in an HTML attribute. You can attach the click handler immediately when you have received the bulb id. After this line:

```
floorPlan.append(img);
```

... just continue with:

```
img.click(function () {
    change(img, bulb.id); // <--- pass the image and the corresponding bulb id
});
```

Then adapt the `change` function as follows (assuming that the fetch response is a lighBulb object):

```
function change(image, bulbId) {
    setBulbStatus(bulbId, function(bulp) {
        image.src = bulb.on ? 'img/bulb-on.png' : 'img/bulb-off.png';
    });
}
```

Also consider using the promise API, since `fetch` returns a promise.